# Как достать данные из JSON React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как из jsonn достать данные для конвертера валют? А именно, поле rate(в json)

console.log(json.rates) - undefined в консоле.

```
function App() {
  const [fromCurrency, setFromCurrency] = React.useState("UAH");
  const [toCurrency, setToCurrency] = React.useState("USD");
  const [fromPrice, setFromPrice] = React.useState(0);
  const [toPrice, setToPrice] = React.useState(0);

  const [rates, setRates] = React.useState({});

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?json")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        setRates(json.rates);
        console.log(json.rates);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.warn(err);
        alert("Не удалось получить информацию");
      });
  }, []);

  const onChangeFromPrice = (value) => {
    const price = value / rates[fromCurrency];
    const result = price * rates[toCurrency];
    setFromPrice(value);
    setToPrice(result);
  };

  const onChangeToPrice = (value) => {
    setToPrice(value);
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Извиняюсь за форматирование, удобнее было отредактировать в редакторе.
И так, судя из вашего кода, в `rates` должен храниться объект, у которого ключом будет валюта (`USD`, `UAH`, `EUR` ...), а значение число `rate`.
Сайт возвращает массив объектов, объекты состоят из:

```json
{
    "cc": "*валюта*",
    "rate": *число*
}
```

... и прочих, которые нам не нужны.

Для того чтобы мы преобразовали к нужному нам формату, мы можем воспользоваться методом `.reduce` у нашего массива (json ответа). Он уже нам вернет нужный нам объект, его мы и присваиваем.

```js
function App()
{
    const [ fromCurrency, setFromCurrency ] = React.useState("UAH");
    const [ toCurrency, setToCurrency ] = React.useState("USD");
    const [ fromPrice, setFromPrice ] = React.useState(0);
    const [ toPrice, setToPrice ] = React.useState(0);

    const [ rates, setRates ] = React.useState({});

    React.useEffect(() =>
    {
        fetch("https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?json")
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((json) =>
            {
                setRates(
                    json.reduce((acc, data) =>
                    {
                        acc[ data.cc ] = data.rate;
                        return acc;
                    }, {})
                );
            })
            .catch((err) =>
            {
                console.warn(err);
                alert("Не удалось получить информацию");
            });
    }, []);

    const onChangeFromPrice = (value) =>
    {
        const price = value / rates[ fromCurrency ];
        const result = price * rates[ toCurrency ];
        setFromPrice(value);
        setToPrice(result);
    };

    const onChangeToPrice = (value) =>
    {
        setToPrice(value);
    };
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!! Все заработало!!!

Comment: Если ответ оказался полезным - нажмите стрелочку вверх и если он решает ваш вопрос, то галочку. Я надеюсь вы поняли вашу ошибку, а не просто получили решение.

Answer (score 2):

скорее всего имя поля неправильно указано, проверьте что у вас в res приходит, возможно опечатка

Comment: В json вот такие данные (поле  rate):                                                                                                                                      [
{
r030: 36,
txt: "Австралійський долар",
rate: 24.2102,
cc: "AUD",
exchangedate: "05.06.2023"
},         если прописываю код (в консоле undefined) :   React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?json")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        setRates(json.rate);
        console.log(json.rate);
      })

Comment: тут  поле rate, а вы хотите получить поле rates его нет, поэтому undef

Comment: Не могу понять, как правильно прописать в строке setRates(json.rate)? Если в json сразу идет массив, а в нем сразу объекты без ключа.. то есть, если бы было вот так {"rates": {rate: 22.0234}} тогда было бы понятно, но потерялась как вытащить rate из объекта, который в массиве)))

Comment: судя по тому что вы написали, у вас в массиве один объект, чтоб его вытащить используйте нулевой индекс, например  json[0] а потом из этого объекта достаньте поле rate , получится что-то вроде json[0].rate

Comment: так получается, достаю курс, но затем другая проблема - что прописать в коде ниже учитывая    
        const [rates, setRates] = React.useState({})?  Деление и умножение не работает тогда(((                                                                                                       
               const onChangeFromPrice = (value) => {
    const price = value / rates[fromCurrency];
    const result = price * rates[toCurrency];
    setFromPrice(value);
    setToPrice(result);
  };

Comment: const price = value / rates[fromCurrency]; 
    const result = price * rates[toCurrency]; уберите здесь квадратные скобки , что было const price = value / rates
    const result = price * rates

Comment: Когда в конвертер ввожу сумму для конвертации, получаю в другой валюте то же самое (например 100 и в другой валюте так же 100). Мне необходимо, например 100 / курс, который я получила вот здесь   setRates(json[0].rate);
        console.log(json[0].rate);

Comment: @ЕвгенийВаулин, отредактируйте свой ответ и внесите в него всю существенную информацию из комментариев, в нынешнем виде это в большей степени комментарий.

Comment: вы представили часть кода,  могу только предположить что проблема в  функции onChangeToPrice , так как он просто принимает значение и его же отдает в хук

Comment: Проверила, проблема именно здесь rates[fromCurrency] - не пойму, как передать rate, который вытягиваю из json ? setRates(json[0].rate)

Comment: Если цифры подставляю - все работает - один курс на другой делится... Если цифры подставляю, все работает const onChangeFromPrice = (value) => {
    const price = value / 2;
    const result = price * 3;
    setFromPrice(value);
    setToPrice(result);
  };     Я так понимаю, мне как-то необходимо передать курс из setRates(json[0].rate)  в хук const [rates, setRates] = React.useState({}); , а затем в вычисление в const price and const result, но как передать не знаю(((  То, что вычисляется в консоле здесь setRates(json[0].rate), дальше не передается(((